# PHP Archive and rename not working together

Tags: php, rename, php-ziparchive

the below function do, to extract a zip folder  to a directory after that zipped folder needs to move to another folder.

It is working some times and not working some times, probability of working function is very low. Hence, i would like to seek your help to optimize and suggest this function should in any kind of environment, it should be independent of operation system.

```
    function extractTo(){
    //This will extract project directory to fetch installable version of TV APP.

    $path='../';
    $filename = 'xyz-v1.22.zip';

    $zipname = $path.$filename;
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if($zip->open($zipname))
    {
        for($i=0; $i<$zip->numFiles; $i++)
        {               //echo 'Filename: '.$zip->getNameIndex($i).'<br />'; 
        }
        if($zip->extractTo('../StadVis/')){ 
            sleep(1); 
            unlink($zipname);

        }else{ 
            return "not success"; 
        }
        $zip->close();

        //chmod('../StadVis/'.$filename1, 0777); 
        if (rename('../'.$filename,'../versions/'.$filename))
        {
        return "success"; 
        //echo "File  Copy";
        }
        else {
        return "not success"; 
        //echo "File Not Copy";

        }

    } 
    else 
    {
        return 'Error reading zip-archive!';
    }
}
```

Comment: No idea why it doesn't work, but you definitely don't need ` sleep(1);`. Did you check the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php)?

Answer (score 0):

1/ Use absolute path in your script :

```
$path=getcwd()."/..";
```

2 / you work in ../ directory so change directory :

```
chdir('../');
```

3/ Combine solution 1 + 2